# C++ how to write an operator that isn't a member function?

Tags: c++

Anyone got an idea on how to write an operator for a class that isn't a member function of the class?

Comment: Arithmetic `operator`s, stream `operator`s, *et cetera* are often not members of a class.

Comment: @Jonathan See for example http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr318.htm.  Yes operators _can_ be global functions.

Comment: Yes I am looking for some sort of global function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it a free function, or a friend function. A good example of this is `operator<<`:

```
class X {
    public:
    int x; 
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const X& x) {
    os << x.x;
    return os;
}
```

The benefit of making it a friend function is that you have direct access to private members, whereas a free function must access all members via public methods.

Comment: `const X & x` means that the parameter `x` is a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) to a `const X`.

Comment: It's an instance of the class X, passed by reference.

Comment: Also why does it have to be reference?

Comment: @Mark: it doesn't have to be. Overloaded operators can take parameters by value if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic `operator`s, stream `operator`s, *et cetera* are often not members of a class. However, they may need to be friends in order to access `private` data members.

I prefer not to use `friend` and to expose methods that can be used by the `operator`s instead. I believe this to be more in keeping with the [Open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), as I could easily add a subtraction operator without editing the class.

These are handy for unit-testing, too (I can "inject" a `std::ostringstream` to test the output of `print()`, for instance).

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Number
{
public:
    Number(int j)
        :i(j)
    {
    }

    void print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << i;
    }

    int value() const
    {
        return i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Number& n)
{
    n.print(os);
    return os;
}

Number operator +(const Number& n, const Number& o)
{
    return Number(n.value() + o.value());
}

int main()
{
    Number a(4), b(5), c(a + b);
    std::cerr << c << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the global function with the operator name:

```
Point operator+(Point& p, Vector& v) {
    return new Point(p.x + q.i, p.y + q.j);
}
```

Comment: To use p.x and q.i you should make this function a friend of Point and Vector of course, or use getters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can take the operator out of the class, and add a parameter to the beginning of the parameter list. In many cases, you will also need to declare the operator function as a friend.

For instance

```
class Foo
{
    Foo operator +( Foo const& other );
};
```

becomes

```
class Foo
{
    friend Foo operator +( Foo const&, Foo const& );
};

Foo operator +( Foo const& first, Foo const& second );
```

The `friend` statement allows the operator to still access any private or protected members needed.

Note that there are some restrictions on which operators can be overloaded in this manner. See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators) for such a list.